# Duplicating nested models on ember.js (after successfull save)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, model, ember-data

I have model campaign, which has nested models stories and domains.

```
App.Campaign = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    stories: DS.hasMany('story'),
    domains: DS.hasMany('domain')
});

App.Domain = DS.Model.extend({
    domain: DS.attr('string'),
    campaigns: DS.hasMany('campaign')
});

App.Story = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    campaign: DS.belongsTo('campaign')
});
```

In controller I create currentCampaign in this way:

```
this.currentCampaign = this.store.createRecord('campaign');
```

And add stories and domains in this way:

```
var campaignDomains = this.get('currentCampaign.domains');
var domainObj = this.store.createRecord('domain', {
    "domain": domain
});
campaignDomains.addObject(domainObj);

var campaignStories = this.get('currentCampaign.stories');
var story = this.store.createRecord('story', {
    "id": this.generateUUID(), // Generate uniqid
    "title": storyTitle,
});
campaignStories.pushObject(story);
```

After saving (before calling transitionTo method I see duplicating domains and stories on template). When I go to page editing campaign I also see duplicating domains and stories. AFter refresh page - I see normal data (by refresh this data are fetching from server).

POST request JSON (domain id are generating on server side, story id are generating on client side):

```
{"campaign":
    {
    "id":"f0777f1a17deadcb",
    "name":"name of campaign",
    "stories":[{
        "id":"488b6b6bf4c988f0",
        "title":"story",
        "campaign":"f0777f1a17deadcb"
    }],
    "domains":[{
        "domain":"domain.com",
        "campaigns":["f0777f1a17deadcb"]}
    }]
}
```

Response on POST request (by adding new campaign):

```
{"campaign":
    {
    "id":"f0777f1a17deadcb",
    "name":"name of campaign",
    "stories":[{
         "id":"488b6b6bf4c988f0",
         "title":"story",
         "campaign":"f0777f1a17deadcb"
    }],
    "domains":[{
         "id":"54",
         "domain":"domain.com",
         "campaigns":["f0777f1a17deadcb"]}
    }]
}
```

Serializer file

```
App.CampaignSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
    attrs: {
        domains: {embedded: 'always'},
        stories: {embedded: 'always'}
    }
});
```

Ember 1.8.1
Ember-data 1.0.0-beta.14.1

Comment: Which version of ember and embed data are you using?

Comment: @Kingpin2k added versions.

Comment: If you duplicate the issue on jsbin, it would make it easier to figure out...

Comment: @KalmanHazins On jsbin we can't emulate response from server.

Comment: True, but there is always mockjax... https://github.com/jakerella/jquery-mockjax

Comment: @KalmanHazins Could you prompt how insert data on jsbin, because I use ember-cli and on output we have only 1 file with all libraries (including jquery, moment, ember etc).

Comment: On jsbin, you would insert them as script tags in your html

Comment: @KalmanHazins Yes, I know, but in my case - I will insert already compiled file by ember-cli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About stories (id of story are generating on client side) I used this.store.push 
instead of this.store.createRecord - and this works fine.

About domains as I understood - this is bug ember.js. On github I found several discussions on this bug.

Now I use one hack to avoid duplicating data, I hope in future this bug will be fixed and I remove my hack.

```
var self = this;
this.get('currentCampaign').save().then(function() {
    self.get('currentCampaign.domains').toArray().forEach(function(domain) {
        if (domain.get('isNew')) {
            domain.deleteRecord();
        }
    });
    self.transitionToRoute('campaigns');
})
```

Comment: Do you need `toArray()` in there?

Comment: @KalmanHazins Yes, because without toArray() call removing works incorrect - in loop we have troubles, because we go out of the array length.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have run into a issue I [reported](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/2666).

I had to downgrade to ember-data 1.0.0-beta.12